# How can I force Excel to treat a column as text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in Excel that contains values such as:

Mar 5934

It's actually not a date, but Excel automatically assumes that it's a date.

How can I force Excel to treat it as text? If I format it as Text, I get the numeric value of the date: 1473449.

I actually want it to be 'Mar 5934' as text, so that the system into which I am importing it reads it correctly.

There are more than 10,000 rows, so I can't edit them manually.

Alternatively, is it possible to copy the formatted "date" into another column as text?

Comment: You must format it as Text **before** you enter the value.

Comment: You can copy your column and paste into notepad. Then copy from notepad and paste into a text-formatted column in Excel.

Comment: You can add an `'` apostrophe in front of the text 'Mar 5934 to convert it to text.  You won't see the apostrophe on the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

- Export the workbook as a CSV file
- Create a new workbook
- Click *Data > From Text/CSV* and select your CSV file
- Set "Data Type Detection" to "Do not detect data types"
- Select the column
- Right-click anywhere in it and select "Format Cells..."
- Set the format to "Text".

Answer (score 1):

a workaround if you're in a hurry:

create new column to the right;
set original column data type to text;
select topmost cell in new column;
enter formula:

```
=TEXT(REF of cell to the left,"?")
```

fill down;
ctrl-c;
paste values on original column;
delete created column